# How to put multiple If statements inside onLoad in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, frontend, jsx

I’m trying to put two *if* statements inside a onload. I tried to put them inside a function like this:

```javascript
onLoad={() => {
    e < index.length ? (e = e) : e++;
    i >= proximo_mes.length ? (i = i) : i++;
}}
```

But the response is different from the first one and the second method (without the function). The second *if* statement is not working. Why?

Without the function:

```
<table id='calendario'>
    <tbody>
        {linhas.map((linha) => (
            <tr key={linha}>
                {colunas.map((coluna, e, i) => (
                    <td
                        key={coluna}
                        onLoad={
                            (e < index.length ? (e = e) : e++,
                            i >= proximo_mes.length ? (i = i) : i++)
                        }
                    ></td>
                ))}
            </tr>
        ))}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This code is nauseating, stop trying to shorten it so much and just use nice traditional if statements and clear variable names. Nothing wrong with adding a little more code to make it comprehendible. I can't even tell what you're trying to accomplish. Also the third argument to `.map` is the original array itself, so `i++` makes no sense

Comment: The two [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#JavaScript) expressions are separated by `;` in the first part and `,` in the second. Is that intentional?